# Which preposition to use with "stay current"?

Tags: prepositions

I am unsure what preposition should be used with "stay current" (staying up to date). Are all these variations valid and have equal meaning?

> stay current *with*
>
> stay current *on*
>
> stay current *in*

The sentence that this will be used in is:

> I stay current [with/on/in] different topics of the computer game industry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *with* is correct.  However, I will demonstrate the way one is supposed to write answers to this type of question.

"We need to keep current with the latest information."

Comment: According to [google](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stay%20current%20with%2C%20stay%20current%20on%2C%20stay%20current%20in&year_start=1990&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstay%20current%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstay%20current%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstay%20current%20in%3B%2Cc0), using "with" is the dominant combination, but "on" and "in" are used too. So are these wrong or just an alternative, which is not as common?

Answer (score 0):

I would say "stay current with". The phrase is used metaphorically (right ?), invoking the idea of a current - something that is flowing. In order to "stay current" you need to flow in the same or similar way, so that you - your knowledge and understanding of the issue - is not moving relative to it.

For this reason, I would use the preposition with.